# Move div upwards and downwards using keyboard arrows

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to be able to move a div with the id `cube` using the keyboard arrows. Going left and right works correctly, but I can't make it go up and down.

```
var output=document.getElementById("output");
var cube=document.getElementById("cube");
var left=0;
var top=0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    output.innerHTML='Key code: ' + e.which + '<br />' + 'Key Name: ' + e.key;
    var key=e.which;

    switch (key) {
      case 38:          //arrow up
        top = top - 10;
        cube.style.top= top + "px";
        cube.style.background="green";
        break;
      case 40:          //arrow down
        top = top + 10;
        cube.style.top= top + "px";
        cube.style.background="#14B4AA";
        break;
      case 39:          //arrow right
        left = left + 10;
        cube.style.left= left + "px";
        cube.style.background="blue";
        break;
      case 37:         //arrow left
        left = left - 10;
        cube.style.left= left + "px";
        cube.style.background="brown";
        break;
    }
});
```

...

Comment: A working snippet will be useful here.

Comment: Please always include all relevant code so we can replicate your issue. Add the HTML and CSS, please

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a global variable named "top".

> top is a host object, it points to the outermost window object and is most useful when used from within a frame
>   https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2007/06/03/javascript-variable-names-you-shouldn-t-use/

Your code works correctly if the variable name is changed, or if it's scoped somewhere other than window (e.g. inside the event listener).

```js
var output=document.getElementById("output");
var cube=document.getElementById("cube");
var left=0;
var t=0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    output.innerHTML='Key code: ' + e.which + '<br />' + 'Key Name: ' + e.key;
    var key=e.which;
    e.preventDefault(); // used to prevent window scroll on up/down keys

    switch (key) {
      case 38:          //arrow up
        t = t - 10;
        cube.style.top= t + "px";
        cube.style.background="green";
        break;
      case 40:          //arrow down
        t = t + 10;
        cube.style.top= t + "px";
        cube.style.background="#14B4AA";
        break;
      case 39:          //arrow right
        left = left + 10;
        cube.style.left= left + "px";
        cube.style.background="blue";
        break;
      case 37:         //arrow left
        left = left - 10;
        cube.style.left= left + "px";
        cube.style.background="brown";
        break;
    }
});
```

```css
#cube {position: absolute}
```

```html
<div id="cube">CUBE</div>
<div id="output">OUTPUT</div>
```

(note when running the above you have to click inside the snippet to get the key events to reach it)

Comment: Thanks actually it was just the fact of calling a variable "top".

Answer (score 0):

You probably just missing `position:absolute;` for cube div.

See the Snippet below:

```js
var output=document.getElementById("output");
var cube=document.getElementById("cube");
var left=0;
var topPx=0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    output.innerHTML='Key code: ' + e.which + '<br />' + 'Key Name: ' + e.key;
    var key=e.which;

    switch (key) {
      case 38:          //arrow up
        topPx = topPx - 10;
        cube.style.top= topPx + "px";
        cube.style.background="green";
        break;
      case 40:          //arrow down
        topPx = topPx + 10;
        cube.style.top= topPx + "px";
        cube.style.background="#14B4AA";
        break;
      case 39:          //arrow right
        left = left + 10;
        cube.style.left= left + "px";
        cube.style.background="blue";
        break;
      case 37:         //arrow left
        left = left - 10;
        cube.style.left= left + "px";
        cube.style.background="brown";
        break;
    }
});
```

```css
#cube{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
}

#output{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
  <div id="cube">
  
  </div>
  <div id="output">
</div>
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/20bk1hrp/)

Comment: Thank you but it was the fact of naming a variable "top"

Answer (score 0):

First, your code does move the cube left and right, but only if you've initially set the cube up with `position:absolute` or `position:relative`. You can't move elements that are in the normal document flow unless you "free them" from that flow with `position`.

The next issue is that you are hard-coding `top` and `left` instead of setting them to values that represent the current location of the cube. You'll need to move them to be inside of your event handler, which will also change their scope and in the case of `top` (which is also a Global variable), this scope change will prevent naming collisions.

Also, instead of getting the values for `top` and `left` from the `.style` property, get them from the final computed style with `getComputedStyle()` because if your element doesn't have an inline style set for it to begin with, `style.top` and `style.left` will return `undefined`.

```js
var output=document.getElementById("output");
var cube=document.getElementById("cube");

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    output.innerHTML='Key code: ' + e.which + '<br />' + 'Key Name: ' + e.key;
    var key=e.which;
    
    // You need to move the cube relative to where it currently is
    // And, you should get the current style based on the final computed value, not the inline style
   var left= parseInt(getComputedStyle(cube).left);
   var top = parseInt(getComputedStyle(cube).top);

    switch (key) {
      case 38:          //arrow up
        top = top - 10;
        cube.style.top= top + "px";
        cube.style.background="green";
        break;
      case 40:          //arrow down
        top = top + 10;
        cube.style.top= top + "px";
        cube.style.background="#14B4AA";
        break;
      case 39:          //arrow right
        left = left + 10;
        cube.style.left= left + "px";
        cube.style.background="blue";
        break;
      case 37:         //arrow left
        left = left - 10;
        cube.style.left= left + "px";
        cube.style.background="brown";
        break;
    }
});
```

```css
#cube { width:50px; height:50px; border:1px solid black; position:absolute; }
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="cube"></div>
```